# I've got PEP 517 error during the glpk installation in python. How can I solve the error?

Tags: python, glpk

This is the error. I tried **pip install --no-use-pep517** and does not work. **pip --upgrade pip**. If it's possible, I want to know other alternatives to glpk.
[image]

Comment: Try conda. `conda install -c anaconda glpk`

Comment: I tried but conda doesn't work on my pc